# Using sass with expressjs

Tags: express, sass

What is the best way to use sass with express.js framework. I am starting from teh point where I have already done

```
npm install sass
```

I believe previously with express 2.x one could do something like -

```
app.use(express.compiler({ src: pub, enable: ['sass'] }))
```

But with express 3.x it gives me error :

```
  app.init();
  return app;
} has no method 'compiler'
```

What is the alternative statement to include in express 3.x?

Similarly if one could let me know the same on how to plugin coffeescript that would be great help.

I have seen examples of using Cakefile to precompile, but is that the only solution? That would mean adding an extra step of running a Cake task. What advantage would that have as against something defined within express app.js / app.coffee.

I have looked at [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets) (which does coffeescript but not sass) and somewhere one also mentioned about [connect-assetmanager](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager) pre hook, but haven't been able to make that work.

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14242584/253576)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x says:

> template engine compliance from `engine.compile(str, options)` => Function to `engine.__express(filename, options, callback)`