# How do you install SASS with Express?

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I am creating a node.js app with Express and socket.io.
I want to use SASS and I see there is a npm package for it, what I don't understand is how do I link between the SASS npm and the app and make it parse the SASS?

UPDATE:
I used SASS middleware https://github.com/andrew/node-sass installed it and included it the following way:

```
  sass = require('node-sass');


app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

  /* other stuff */

  sass.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets',
    debug: true
  });
});
```

But it still doesn't work

Comment: Not exactly what the OP asked for (hence not an answer), but for posterity, Express provides a generator through the `express-generator` package, and you can run `express --css compass` and the generator will automatically set up Express with Compass. I see little reasons to use Sass but not Compass.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use the sass middleware, for example [this one](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass).

Quoting from docs:

```
var server = connect.createServer(
   sass.middleware({
       src: __dirname
       , dest: __dirname + '/public'
       , debug: true
    }),
   connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
);
```

in case of using express, just add:

```
 app.use(
     sass.middleware({
         src: __dirname + '/sass', //where the sass files are 
         dest: __dirname + '/public', //where css should go
         debug: true // obvious
     })
 );
```

to your `app.configure()` call.

Of course on production systems it's a better idea to precompile sass to css.

**update**

In the example above the middleware will look for `sass` files in `__dirname + '/sass/css'`. Also by default it looks for files with `.scss` extension. There doesn't seem to be an option to change the extension.

Comment: thanx, if I don't put the `sass.middleware` inside `createServer` where do I put it?

Comment: inside `app.configure` call or wherever you have your middleware configured

Comment: if you're not sure where it is, look for `app.use` calls

Comment: where do I put the SASS file?

Comment: @IlyaD in the directory pointed to by `src` property in middleware configuration (`/sass` subdirectory in your web app root)

Comment: I used `dest: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets/sass',` and nothing happens.. I'm new to Express, so is there something I'm missing? How do I know it even tries to compile it? (and thanx for the help :)

Comment: @IlyaD use that as src. dest is where compiled css go.

Comment: still no joy, I updated the question. It is suppose to compile on page request, right?

Comment: thanx! so this means I can only use SCSS and not SASS?

Comment: @IlyaD i didn't try but looking at the code and knowing it's a binding to libsass it's just the extension. But it's best to simply try.

Comment: I *just* (5 minutes ago) emailed the creator of libsass, and he confirmed that libsass does not handle the indented SASS syntax.  So, yes, SCSS is the only option at present.

Comment: Is there a way to set ``source`` to not append ``/css``?  ``source`` is set to ``/Users/username/project/public/sass/css/style.scss``, with ``/css`` appended.

Comment: @user1429980: Finally figured out how to do that: The reason /css is appended is because that's what you request in the html: `<link ... href="css/style.css"/>`. This requests the `css/style.css` file, which invokes the compiler on `scss/css/style.css`. Instead, if you change the link to `<link ... href="style.css">`, and change the src to include "/css", things will all work as you want.

Comment: Hm, I take that back. Now the SCSS compiler will run on the right file, but you'll get a 404 since express will look for `style.css` in `public/style.css` instead of `public/stylesheets/style.css`... Not sure if there's an easy way to fix this.

Comment: @AchalDave, but that would not be maintainable if you to removed the sass middleware... not a good solution.

Comment: @soulcheck is there a significant overhead to using a middleware for compiling SCSS instead of compiling them via grunt or other tools in advance? My concern is if Express middleware will try to check if there have been any SCSS changes on every single request.

Comment: @user1429980, the appending of /css happened to me as well. The trick (which I figured out by looking at the node-sass source code) is to include [the prefix option](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass#connectexpress-middleware) for node-sass. Prefix gets cut out of the requested path, so eg. with prefix /css a request to /css/style.css gets "processed" as /style.css. Seems irrelevant, but it's worth trying. At least it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Sass middleware has moved to https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware

Answer (score 11):

If you are using express-generator Then try

```
express --view=ejs --css=sass
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on various sources including the threads/comments above:

**node:**

```
var connect = require('connect');
var sass = require('node-sass');

var srcPath = __dirname + '/sass';
var destPath = __dirname + '/public/styles';

var server = connect.createServer(
    sass.middleware({
        src: srcPath,
        dest: destPath,
        debug: true,
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        prefix: '/styles'
    }),
    connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
);
```

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
etc
```

**file system:**

rootDirectory / server.js (this is the node app)

rootDirectory / public / styles / (this is where the compiled scss files will appear)

rootDirectory / sass / main.scss

This works for me and I've forked the example at:

[node-sass-example](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass-example)

here:

[node-sass-example using prefix](https://github.com/swervo/node-sass-example)

Comment: Pull-request was accepted so the node-sass-example should reflect my changes now.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like implementation has changed a bit for Express. I had to do this instead:

```
npm install node-sass-middleware --save
```

then

```
var sass = require('node-sass-middleware');

 app.use(
     sass({
         src: __dirname + '/sass',    // Input SASS files
         dest: __dirname + '/public', // Output CSS
         debug: true                
     })
 );
```