# Polymer 1.1 and SASS

Tags: sass, polymer

For some reason there is no information available on how to use sass and polymer together. First I tried the following:

```
<dom-module id="app-header">
    <link rel="import" type="css" href="../css/app-header.css">

    <template> 
        ...
```

Here the stylesheet is external and I can easily transform my scss into css.

Although this works, the styles are applied to the whole document.

Anyway, in Polymer's [1.1 release](https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/08/13/1.1-release/) this is deprecated and although there is a way to share styles you still have your css inside a template tag

```
<!-- shared-styles.html -->
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
    <template>
        <style>
            .warning {
                color: red;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

What would be the best way to use scss with polymer 1.1 ?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354396/polymer-and-sass/33875597#33875597 I think could be useful for you also.

Comment: thanks for mentioning! I've done exactly that :)

Comment: I'm glad you did it !! Great !!

Comment: You can to use "gulp-inject-string". See more: https://gist.github.com/horacioibrahim/70ea32c9ba06a7d2d2632995c47149b4

Answer (score 3):

In Polymer 1.1 external stylesheets have been deprecated in favour of "style-modules".

[My solution was to create a bash script](http://stonelab.work/blog/2016/05/22/here-is-how-to-use-polymer-with-scss/) which takes the output of the scss transpiler and wraps it in a custom style module definition.

I attached this script to a PHPStorm file watcher and all i have to do is modify my SCSS and everything is auto generated.