# Is it possible to reference the polymer css variables in a Angular2 component context?

Tags: angular, polymer, components, polymer-1.0

I am trying to access the mixin and vars properties of polymer in a Ng2 Component style "my-comp-style.scss".
ie:

```
@apply(--shadow-elevation-2dp);
background: var(--primary-color, #666);
```

but the --shadow-elevation and the --primary-color are not interpreted. Is there a way to fix this ? It would be great not to have to duplicate of the mixins and vars.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly these links can help:

Rob from the Polymer team tells how to use Polymer + Saas.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xA2hxpGS7yw

And another Stack Overflow thread: 
[How to use Sass inside a Polymer component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354396/how-to-use-sass-inside-a-polymer-component)

Answer (score 0):

Styles and external stylesheets (both CSS and SASS) referenced in a component are added as `<style>` tags to the `<head>`, when you're not using `ViewEncapsulation.Native`.

Remember that some browsers support CSS variables natively, but no browser supports the CSS `@apply` mixin. Polymer uses ShadyCSS to do this processing.

Polymer 1.x is expecting a `<style is="custom-style"></style>`

Polymer 2.x is expecting a `<custom-style><style></style></custom-style>`

You can write a service to scan the `<head>` after a component is created in `ngOnInit()` and add `is="custom-style"` or wrap with `<custom-style>` to make ShadyCSS work.

This is the strategy I use in [Origami](https://github.com/hotforfeature/origami/blob/master/src/style/custom-style.service.ts) to make Angular and Polymer 2 styles work together.