# How to make node-sass-middleware module process SCSS files?

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I'm trying to make node-sass-middleware work for scss files. I belive this can be done because of an answer in this question: [How to install SASS with Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242536/how-to-install-sass-with-express)
that mentions that node-sass module also looks at scss files. Here is my implementation, almost as the one on the repository guide:

```
app.use(sass({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
  debug: true,
  indentedSyntax: true,
  sourceMap: true
}));
```

And the error:

```
  source: C:\Users\[...]\public\stylesheets\style.sass
  dest: C:\Users\[...]\public\stylesheets\style.css
  read: C:\Users\[...]\public\stylesheets\style.css
GET /stylesheets/style.css 404 5.242 ms - 1116
```

Is it possible that this function is not working on this library? Is there a way to make it look at scss files?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easy. I found it when reading through the repository documentation: Just put `indentedSyntax:` paramter to `false`.